# Serializing function objects

Tags: c++, serialization, c++11, closures, function-object

Is it possible to serialize and deserialize a `std::function`, a function object, or a closure in general in C++? How? Does C++11 facilitate this? Is there any library support available for such a task (e.g., in Boost)?

For example, suppose a C++ program has a `std::function` which is needed to be communicated (say via a TCP/IP socket) to another C++ program residing on another machine. What do you suggest in such a scenario?

---

**Edit:**

To clarify, the functions which are to be moved are supposed to be pure and side-effect-free. So I do not have security or state-mismatch problems.

A solution to the problem is to build a small embedded domain specific language and serialize its abstract syntax tree.
I was hoping that I could find some language/library support for moving a machine-independent representation of functions instead.

Comment: Forget it. Look up the concept of a "remote procedure call", and popular implementations for it.

Comment: No, no, and no. Any such object, when you peel off pretty typesafe wrappers, is a pointer to some machine code. You cannot send neither machine code nor pointers to other processes or other machines.

Comment: @kerrek-sb I am not sure if RPC fits my purpose where I have a lot of small function objects constructed and deconstructed continuously in the sender side. It would be much nicer to somehow transmit the logic itself.

Comment: @n-m I see. Seems logical that you can not expect to transmit machine-dependent code and execute it somewhere else. Looks like that I am looking for a machine-independent (and movable) representation of the function logics in C++ which does not exist.

Comment: Do note that there is a host of considerations that are language-independent.

Comment: @luc-danton Could you elaborate on this? What may go wrong if I serialize the syntax tree of a small embedded DSL of mine and transmit it as a workaround for my problem?

Comment: how about you send build a dynamic linked library with that function, send it over ip and load it on target.
Still, i think your best bet is an interpreted scripting language.

Comment: @shaniaki Security considerations abound in the general case. They don't apply (or not to the same extent anyway) if you reduce the problem to a DSL which presumably only has limited functionality -- you may want to amend your question if you're set on that solution. You do have the matter (in both situations) of what should operations be applied on in the case that they're not pure and can reach some state -- when and how is this state sync'd between machines?

Comment: Is the receiver the same program as the sender, or can it link to it/include it? If so, you just need to have and send a unique identifier for a function and the function arguments, and the other process will be able to look it up and make the function call.

Comment: @n.m. What if we write a library to, read the machine code, send them as binary data, use some library to do binary translation, and execute it? It seems possible if we only target to several widely used architectures. (for example, the library can support only linux x86+x86_64) (however, I also agree that we should use rpc rather than sending binary code now.)

Comment: @recolic Do you want to implement this? You need to decompile the code before sending and include any objects it references, and any code it calls, and any objects referenced by code it calls, recursively. I'm not holding my breath.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

C++ has no built-in support for serialization and was never conceived with the idea of transmitting code from one process to another, lest one machine to another. Languages that may do so generally feature both an IR (intermediate representation of the code that is machine independent) and reflection.

So you are left with writing yourself a protocol for transmitting the actions you want, and the DSL approach is certainly workable... depending on the variety of tasks you wish to perform and the need for performance.

Another solution would be to go with an existing language. For example the Redis NoSQL database embeds a LUA engine and may execute LUA scripts, you could do the same and transmit LUA scripts on the network.

Answer (score 14):

Yes for function pointers and closures. Not for `std::function`.

A function pointer is the simplest — it is just a pointer like any other so you can just read it as bytes:

```cpp
template <typename _Res, typename... _Args>
std::string serialize(_Res (*fn_ptr)(_Args...)) {
  return std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&fn_ptr), sizeof(fn_ptr));
}

template <typename _Res, typename... _Args>
_Res (*deserialize(std::string str))(_Args...) {
  return *reinterpret_cast<_Res (**)(_Args...)>(const_cast<char*>(str.c_str()));
}
```

But I was surprised to find that even without recompilation the address of a function will change on every invocation of the program. Not very useful if you want to transmit the address. This is due to [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), which you can turn off on Linux by starting `your_program` with `setarch $(uname -m) -LR your_program`.

Now you can send the function pointer to a different machine running the same program, and call it! (This does not involve transmitting executable code. But unless you are generating executable code at run-time, I don't think you are looking for that.)

A lambda function is quite different.

```
std::function<int(int)> addN(int N) {
  auto f = [=](int x){ return x + N; };
  return f;
}
```

The value of `f` will be the captured `int N`. Its representation in memory is the same as an `int`! The compiler generates an unnamed class for the lambda, of which `f` is an instance. This class has `operator()` overloaded with our code.

The class being unnamed presents a problem for serialization. It also presents a problem for returning lambda functions from functions. The latter problem is solved by `std::function`.

`std::function` as far as I understand is implemented by creating a templated wrapper class which effectively holds a reference to the unnamed class behind the lambda function through the template type parameter. (This is `_Function_handler` in [functional](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/functional).) `std::function` takes a function pointer to a static method (`_M_invoke`) of this wrapper class and stores that plus the closure value.

Unfortunately, everything is buried in `private` members and the size of the closure value is not stored. (It does not need to, because the lambda function knows its size.)

So `std::function` does not lend itself to serialization, but works well as a blueprint. I followed what it does, simplified it a lot (I only wanted to serialize lambdas, not the myriad other callable things), saved the size of the closure value in a `size_t`, and added methods for (de)serialization. It works!

Comment: But this would be architecture dependent.  For instance this wouldn't work from x86 to arm.

Comment: @daniel could you put up your code for the last bit with the `std::function`

Comment: I did it at work, so I'll have to ask for a copyright release first. I'll report back!

Comment: @DanielDarabos, nice technical answer. In C++11, `std::function` has a member called `target()` which "Returns a pointer to the stored callable function target."  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target . Even without that, can you assume that you can reinterpret_cast from std::function to get the pointer and keep doing assumptions. Not portable, but after all, your answer is platform dependent already.

Answer (score 0):

No, but there are some restricted solutions.

The most you can hope for is to register functions in some sort of global map (e.g. with key strings) that is common to the sending code and the receiving code (either in different computers or before and after serialization). 
You can then serialize the string associated with the function and get it on the other side.

As a concrete example the library HPX implements something like this, in something called [HPX_ACTION](http://stellar.cct.lsu.edu/files/hpx-0.9.10/html/hpx/manual/applying_actions/action_invocation.html).

This requires a lot of protocol and it is fragile with respect to changes in code.

But after all this is no different from something that tries to serialize a class with private data. In some sense the code of the function is its private part (the arguments and return interface is the public part).

What leaves you a slip of hope is that depending on how you organize the code these "objects" can be global or common and if all goes right they are available during serialization and deserialization through some kind predefined runtime indirection.

This is a crude example:

serializer code:

```
// common:
class C{
  double d;
  public:
  C(double d) : d(d){}
  operator(double x) const{return d*x;}
};
C c1{1.};
C c2{2.};
std::map<std::string, C*> const m{{"c1", &c1}, {"c2", &c2}};
// :common

main(int argc, char** argv){
   C* f = (argc == 2)?&c1:&c2;
   (*f)(5.); // print 5 or 10 depending on the runtime args
   serialize(f); // somehow write "c1" or "c2" to a file
}
```

deserializer code:

```
// common:
class C{
  double d;
  public:
  operator(double x){return d*x;}
};
C c1;
C c2;
std::map<std::string, C*> const m{{"c1", &c1}, {"c2", &c2}};
// :common

main(){
   C* f;
   deserialize(f); // somehow read "c1" or "c2" and assign the pointer from the translation "map"
   (*f)(3.); // print 3 or 6 depending on the code of the **other** run
}
```

(code not tested).

Note that this forces a lot of common and consistent code, but depending on the environment you might be able to guarantee this.
The slightest change in the code can produce a hard to detect logical bug.

Also, I played here with global objects (which can be used on free functions) but the same can be done with scoped objects, what becomes trickier is how to establish the map locally (`#include` common code inside a local scope?)